# Getting toll data from Google Maps or other maps provider for a given route in a mobile app

Tags: google-maps, mobile, gps, openstreetmap, here-api

I am building a mobile app for users to use when driving. It will keep track of the user's location, and at the end of the trip it will tell the user the distance travelled, and the cost of the trip.

The cost of the trip will be calculated by the distance travelled * cost per km and any additional toll costs. The issue I have now is getting the toll data.

1. What maps provider can I use to get this toll data reliably? I heard Google Maps, HERE maps and OpenStreetMaps have them.
2. How do I get toll data? I looked around online and could find that they can provide the toll data if the route is pre-calculated by the map provider (I send in the start and end location). For my app, I'm unsure where to look or what to look for. I guess I will be storing a series of GPS coordinates as the user drives, do I just send all these coordinates to some API to process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On OpenStreetMap, while [tolls sections are mapped](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:toll), the fees amount are not present, as they are a non-geographical feature. However, an external database could be used in conjection of OSM data to keep track of these fees.

Answer (score 3):

[Tollsmart](http://www.tollsmart.com/developers/) has APIs for all tunnels, bridges and toll roads in the US & Canada and yes you can just send the coordinates and it will calculate the toll costs for the route. Note that there are many variable such as vehicle size, time of day (peak and off-peak pricing), transponder discounts (i.e., E-ZPass). Our APIs can handle all these variables and more.

Comment: BTW: your contact email lacks the 't' if you click on it

Comment: Please be sure to explicitly state your affiliation to products you promote. (I'm assuming you are [this Jim Kovarik](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jimkovarik/))

Answer (score 1):

As Eric mentioned toll sections are in OSM but not the costs. IF you have the costs for the sections you can integrate them into existing OSM routing engines: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

E.g. for Germany the costs are available [here](https://www.toll-collect.de/en/web/public/toll_collect/rund_um_die_maut/maut_tarife/maut_tarife_2015.html)

Answer (score 0):

HERE has a API which also calculates tolls based on different parameters, check Toll Cost Extension
https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/toll-cost/topics/quick-start.html

Comment: can we use this API to calculate route lat-long instead of route linked ID ?

Answer (score 0):

PTV xServer can also compute Toll & Costs based on Navteq data http://xserver.ptvgroup.com/en-uk/use-cases/toll-calculation/